# Apply time series decomposition on more than one data

Tags: r, time-series

I am doing time series analysis. I have sales data for different products for three years. I want to apply time series decomposition using decompose() in R, on each products data and want the output in the same file, means want to have seasonal,trend and other components as columns in the same data.

Data Information:
Columns - Product,Year, Month, Sales

Data: 
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7GTV25JHGcDb3VhRnRUdmJwRVE&usp=sharing

Thanks in advance...

Let me know if you need further information

Comment: Please help us help you by providing us with a reproducible example (i.e. code and example data), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for details. Right now your question is too vague and broad.

Comment: I have attached the data (Data) and the format of the output ( Output_format). Hope, everything is clear now. Thanks for your response.